# Accessing elements of an dictionary with keys and values as lists

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist

How do i access the elements of a dictionary that contains keys as list of 2 strings and values as list of floats of finite unknown length?

Comment: just as you would with any other dictonary. Can we have an example please?

Comment: you mean, the keys are _tuples_ of 2 strings? lists, being mutable, can't be keys. unless you mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

Dict key can't be a list in Python(a mutable object), It should be immutable ([hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash)) object. Yes you can have tuple of strings as key. e.g.

```
 d = { ('aa', 'bb'): 10}
```

is fine. And to index it just do like:

```
 v = d[('aa', 'bb')]
```

Working example:

```
>>> d = { ('aa', 'bb'): 10}  
>>> d['aa', 'bb']
10
>>>
```

You should read [How are dictionaries implemented?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-dictionaries-implemented)

Comment: For completeness, the parentheses are optional in the 2nd example. So, `v = d['aa,'bb']` also works.

Comment: @Robᵩ wow..interesting..It should be I didn't try this I uses `(` `)` thanks.

Comment: But its better to have () right, it makes easier to read.

Comment: @yopy After @ Robᵩ comment I feel `d['aa', 'bb']` is much better `'aa', 'bb'` always be a tuple (and tuples are ordered collection).

Comment: ya agree, addition tuple is hashable only when the object inside the tuple are hashable else not. so not every tuples couldn't be a dictionary key.

Comment: @yopy yes and 'tuple of strings' is hashable object.